# Can't recover MtGox password

Tags: mtgox

I go to:

https://mtgox.com/users/login

Click on "Forgot your password?".   Enter "User Name or email".  Click on "Recover my password".

Nothing happens.  They say " We will email you a link to reset your password."  But they don't.

Is there some way to get past this?  Is there some way to contact someone who maintains the site about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MtGox support is available on https://support.mtgox.com, by email (support AT mtgox.com) and on IRC freenode server channel #mtgox.

You could try to check your spam folder if you are using a bad webmail provider or bad antispam.

Comment: doesn't work, email is not working, and the same for the website...

Comment: @DanKrajčovič: [MtGox went insolvent last year](http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/538/5406).

Comment: this answer is from 2011 ! theres no more mtgox. only a bankruptcy process on https://claims.mtgox.com/